# How to convert 32digit long info hash to 40 digit long info hash in python?

Tags: python, hash, bittorrent

Some websites such as Sumotorrent.com use the magnet link with the 32 digit long hash, but my code is designed to store and work with 40 digit long hash?

Comment: @vartec @GWW @dan04 @Seth-Johnson @Scott-Griffiths   please do refer to the answer provided by  @hammar Lack of knowledge on your part does not always mean that a question is wrong or vague, and there is no vague questions specialy in Computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info hash in those magnet links appear to be encoded in Base32, while the info hash used in bittorrent is in hexadecimal (i.e. Base16). This appears to give consistent results:

```
import base64
base64.b16encode(base64.b32decode("<your hash goes here>"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily 32 is smaller than 40, so you can just pad with 8 zeroes without losing information.

Comment: @recursive mate the 32 long one is in a different base and the 40 long one is in a different one, you cant just pad it, I rather was asking about how convert the 32 long one to the 40 long one's base

Comment: @Max: Different base as in different radix?  If so,  just tell us they are, instead of making us have to guess.

Comment: @recursive  :p mate if I knew would have googled " how to convert from base x to y"

Comment: @Max: So you are asking how to convert a 32 digit number in an unknown base to a 40 digit number in another unknown base?  I'm just trying to understand.  And even if you don't know there still may be a way to do it.

Comment: @recursive  well technically it is not unknown, people who know about bittorrent are suppose to know which is which :P but apparently I am not one of them!!

Comment: @Max: Ok, what radix is your 40 digit hash in?